# Is showing a graph is non-Hamiltonian NP-Complete?

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, np-complete, hamiltonian-path

> Show that graph is not Hamiltonian. Is this an NP-complete problem?

My guess is that this is not an NP-complete problem, because we can run DFS and check it.  Like, if we have a Hamiltonian cycle than there is a path that can be traced with DFS that covers all vertices and comes back to the original source. Right?

I am not exactly sure though. Maybe my assumption is stupid! I just started to read on NP-complete problems. Need your help here...

Comment: Showing that NOT-HAMCYCLE is NP-**hard** is a reasonable undergrad CS exercise.  Showing that it is NP-**complete** would upend theoretical computer science.  Are you sure you're not being asked to demonstrate the former?

Comment: @KyleJones I am not asked to demonstrate anything.. this is a question professor asked us during the lecture and nobody answered. So I am just curious

Answer (score 5):

You probably know that showing a graph *is* Hamiltonian is an NP-complete problem.  Thus, showing that a graph is *not* Hamiltonian is a co-NP-complete problem.  It is an open problem as to whether or not a co-NP-complete problem can also be NP-complete.

So, the short answer is, "we don't know yet!"

Answer (score 1):

**(This answer is wrong but by virtue of apnortons comment below it might yet prove instructional to someone else but me)**

I'm a bit in doubt after reading the authorative answer by apnorton, but it seems to me the NP-completeness of (is-not-Hamiltonian) can still be proven. For this one would need to *a)* show that (is-not-Hamiltonian) is in NP and *b)* find a polynomial time reduction of (is-Hamiltonian) or another NP-complete problem to (is-not-Hamiltonian).

The first property can be proven by demonstrating a verifier for the problem, i.e. a deterministic Turing machine that accepts or rejects a given candidate solution in polynomial time. It's a bit of handwaving, but I'd imagine this can be constructed analogously to a verifier for (is-Hamiltonian).

The second property can be demonstrated by showing that $\neg$ (is-Hamiltonian) is equivalent to (is-not-Hamiltonian) $\cup$ (syntactically incorrect graph encodings). Assuming there exist polynomial time syntactical validation procedures for graph encodings, this constitutes a polynomial time reduction and so (is-not-Hamiltionian) would be NP-complete.

Comment: You'd need a **polynomial-time** deterministic verifier for (is-not-Hamiltonian), not just a deterministic verifier, to prove (is-not-Hamiltonian) is in NP.  This (NP = coNP) would flip the wigs of most theoreticians as much as if P turned out to be equivalent to NP.  Tough get for a class assignment, which this question clearly is.

Comment: Your "first property" hand-waving is unsound.  This is because verifying the *existence* of something is easy (just check that *one* solution is valid), while verifying the *nonexistence* of something is very hard (for this, you'd have somehow check that *no possible* solution is valid if you were to use the same approach as before.

Comment: @apnorton Thanks for the clarification. Your answer popped up just as I was wrapping up, so I thought I'd leave mine for further comments. I can see what you mean and I appreciate your explanation.